# Created a new Android project and it crashes when running on a phone

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, compiler-errors

I have existing project in Eclipse for Android that all still run with no issues.

It's been a while since I have been on Android and I created a new one from scratch. However, it crashes when testing to a phone (Samsung s3) and I can't figure out why. All the settings seem just the same as my other projects that still work. I get a Source Not Found error. Tried many suggestions on here without luck.

Maybe it's a case of I haven't done enough as I have done the bare minimum. Project tree, manifest, java class and xml below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Error:

[image]

[image]

Log Cat text around the time of crash:

```
10-31 19:28:10.536: I/ActivityManager(2361): Process com.mcsapp (pid 30623) (adj 0) has died.
10-31 19:28:10.536: W/ActivityManager(2361): mDVFSHelper.acquire()
10-31 19:28:10.546: E/ViewRootImpl(2361): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
10-31 19:28:10.561: D/dalvikvm(30720): Late-enabling CheckJNI
10-31 19:28:10.586: V/WindowManager(2361): Window{42d28228 u0 Keyguard}mOrientationRequetedFromKeyguard=false
10-31 19:28:10.586: D/WindowManager(2361): computeScreenConfigurationLocked() set config.orientation=1 dw=720 dh=1280 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.updateOrientationFromAppTokensLocked:5171 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.updateOrientationFromAppTokens:5142 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.realStartActivityLocked:1021 
10-31 19:28:10.586: D/PowerManagerService(2361): setKeyboardVisibility: false
10-31 19:28:10.596: V/WindowManager(2361): Window{42d28228 u0 Keyguard}mOrientationRequetedFromKeyguard=false
10-31 19:28:10.621: D/AndroidRuntime(30720): Shutting down VM
10-31 19:28:10.621: W/dalvikvm(30720): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c37700)
10-31 19:28:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(30720): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 19:28:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(30720): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mcsapp/com.mcsapp.McsHome}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mcsapp.McsHome" on path: /data/app/com.mcsapp-1.apk
10-31 19:28:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(30720):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2219)
10-31 19:28:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(30720):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
10-31 19:28:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(30720):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
10-31 19:28:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(30720):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
10-31 19:28:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(30720):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-31 19:28:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(30720):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
10-31 19:28:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(30720):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
10-31 19:28:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(30720):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 19:28:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(30720):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-31 19:28:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(30720):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
10-31 19:28:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(30720):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
10-31 19:28:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(30720):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-31 19:28:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(30720): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mcsapp.McsHome" on path: /data/app/com.mcsapp-1.apk
10-31 19:28:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(30720):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
10-31 19:28:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(30720):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-31 19:28:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(30720):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-31 19:28:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(30720):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
10-31 19:28:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(30720):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
10-31 19:28:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(30720):    ... 11 more
10-31 19:28:10.626: I/ActivityManager(2361): Notify an ApplicationCrash
10-31 19:28:10.791: V/LvOutput(1934): initCheck: 0
10-31 19:28:10.791: V/LvOutput(1934): detachEffects: detach processing for output 2, stream 1, session 128
```

Comment: change minimumsdk version in androidmanifest.xml  to 8 in place of 18

Comment: @raj, why would you suggest that ?

Comment: post `logcat` what error u get

Comment: Dan, are you getting *EDIT SOURCE LOOKUP PATH* after Source Not Found ?

Comment: add a .McsHome in the activity declared in the manifest

Comment: if still anything happens or goes wrong.. try renaming the package name something like com.example.mcs in src and also in manifest

Comment: Yes @2Dee I am! I've added screenshots to the opening post

Comment: @kaushik I've added the log cat text from around the time of crash to the opening post

Comment: Did you download the Android source code in the SDK Manager ? The error looks like your trying to follow method calls when in debug mode and the IDE can't follow the calls made by the framework itself. Hopefully I made myself clear and this will help ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can see in my first screenshot that I had "mcsapp" package name under "src". When looking at the logcat error it was stating it couldn't find said class under "com.mcsapp", so I created a new package named "com.mcsapp" and moved my class into it.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you got `Activity not found error` because you forget to add `.` to your Activity in `manifest.xml`

```
<activity
        android:name=".McsHome"
        ........../>
```

I am not sure about try this..

Comment: This made no difference. I have added the error I get to the opening post.